# Determine overall rank of items grouped by date in tidy data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

The goal is to determine which company ranks highest by rate over the time period of the data. I thought one way to do this would be to arrange the companies within each date and assign a rank. Then add up the ranks for each company. The company with the lowest value of that sum wins.

```
df <- tibble(
  comp =  rep(letters[1:3], 4),
  rate = c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 0.9, 1, 1.2, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.1, 1),
  date = c(rep(Sys.Date()-3, 3), rep(Sys.Date()-2, 3), 
           rep(Sys.Date()-1, 3), rep(Sys.Date(), 3))
            )
```

Clearly I'm missing something about group_by

```
df |> group_by(date) |> 
  arrange(rate)

# A tibble: 12 × 3
# Groups:   date [4]
   comp   rate date      
   <chr> <dbl> <date>    
 1 a       0.9 2023-02-04
 2 a       1   2023-02-03
 3 b       1   2023-02-04
 4 a       1   2023-02-05
 5 c       1   2023-02-06
 6 b       1.1 2023-02-03
 7 b       1.1 2023-02-06
 8 c       1.2 2023-02-03
 9 c       1.2 2023-02-04
10 b       1.2 2023-02-05
11 c       1.4 2023-02-05
12 a       1.5 2023-02-06
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: ```df %>% group_by(date) %>% arrange(date, desc(rate)) %>% mutate(rnk = rank(-rate))``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  arrange(date, desc(rate)) %>% 
  mutate(rnk = rank(-rate))

#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   date [4]
#>    comp   rate date         rnk
#>    <chr> <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 c       1.2 2023-02-03     1
#>  2 b       1.1 2023-02-03     2
#>  3 a       1   2023-02-03     3
#>  4 c       1.2 2023-02-04     1
#>  5 b       1   2023-02-04     2
#>  6 a       0.9 2023-02-04     3
#>  7 c       1.4 2023-02-05     1
#>  8 b       1.2 2023-02-05     2
#>  9 a       1   2023-02-05     3
#> 10 a       1.5 2023-02-06     1
#> 11 b       1.1 2023-02-06     2
#> 12 c       1   2023-02-06     3
```

You can summarise this however you like:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  arrange(date, rate) %>% 
  mutate(rnk = rank(rate)) %>% 
  group_by(comp) %>% 
  summarise(full_rank = sum(rnk))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want :

```
df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(rate)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(comp) %>%
  summarise(rank = sum(rank))
```

output

```
  comp   rank
  <chr> <int>
1 a         6
2 b         8
3 c        10
```